# Update a field in a table according to a query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMER_EmployeeID
FROM   (SELECT [EMER_EmployeeID],
               [EMER_Employee_StatusDateS]
        FROM   [dbo].[EmployeeERP] AS B
        WHERE  [EMER_ClassCode] NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3, 5,
                                         6, 8 )
               AND [EMER_Employee_StatusCode] NOT IN ( 3, 4, 5, 6,
                                                       68, 0, 1, 9 )) AS t
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[MonthlySalary] AS K
         ON K.MS_EmployeeID = T.EMER_EmployeeID
WHERE  K.MS_Month > 2 + ( CAST(CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH([EMER_Employee_StatusDateS])), 2) AS FLOAT) AS INT) )
```

That give me a list of ID'S.

I have another table - call her TB:

```
TE_EmployeeID
TE_IsCheck
```

I wrote this to make all TE_IsCheck Zero:
    Update TB set  [TE_IsCheck]= 0

Now, I want to update to 1 the field TE_IsCheck  according to list in the 'Big' Query. How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: `2 + ( CAST(CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH([EMER_Employee_StatusDateS])), 2) AS FLOAT) AS INT) ) ` seems completely unnecessarily complex. Why not `2 + MONTH([EMER_Employee_StatusDateS])`?

Comment: month is an int while StatusDateS is "2015-15-10" so I had to split the month and then convert to int.

Comment: Try `2 + MONTH([EMER_Employee_StatusDateS])` - It should do the same thing as your convoluted expression. Trimmng integers and adding leading zeroes and casting to float then int isn't going to change the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `update`.  Say, something like this:

```
with ids as (
      <your query here>
     )
update tb
    set TE_IsCheck = 1
    where tb.TE_EmployeeID in (select EMER_EmployeeID from ids);
```